# Unexpected Disconnection with Code 1006 on Windows Server Hosted on Azure

Tags: node.js, windows, azure, websocket

My application does client authorization over WebSocket connection using [ws@7](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) but after several minutes suddenly it gets disconnected with the error code 1006.

Interesting thing is it's working on AWS Windows Server instances but not on Azure instances or VMWare VMs. I assume there is some kind of configuration related to WebSockets should be handled before installing Node-based application but the main question is what I have to configure in order to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

1006 error usually happens when there is a timeout. In the library you are using, the ws timeout is 30 seconds: https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/4f293a8726092c75539287dd07358afaf151a2e5/lib/websocket.js
Check whether you are using a gateway or something in between the VM with a timeout less or equal than the ping interval that ws automatically does from the client.

You can usually can see this automatically generated ping messages in Firefox with the F12 tools in the network tab, these do not show up in Chrome nor in Edge but they happen as well:

[image: Ping pong messages as seen in Firefox]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with my Windows machine tryng to connect a server using Visual Studio Code. I have reset the routes, and reboot the machine, that solve the issue.

To reset use:

```
route -f
```